# How can I convert a matrix into characters?

Tags: python, matrix, vector

```
classes = ['A', 'B', 'C']

my_data = [
    [2, 1, 3],
    [1, 1, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [3, 1, 3],
    [3, 1, 3],
    [3, 3, 2]
]
```

Here, A = 1, B=2, and C=3.

Suppose, I want to first find the maximum value in each row of the matrix `my_data`, and then I want to convert them into characters from `classes`.

Can I do it in python without using loops?

The following source code is not working for me:

```
def prediction_to_name(pred):
    return classes[np.argmax(pred)]
```

Comment: What kinds of loops specifically do you want to avoid and why?  You're describing an iterative process so there will be *some* kind of loop involved.  You also haven't specified how the numbers map to the characters in `classes`, and your `my_data` isn't formatted correctly (there should be commas between the list items).

Comment: @Samwise, plz, check the edit.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Alexander, a single list/vector of characters.

Comment: @user366312 can you please edit `my_data` so that it's accepted as valid input by a Python interpreter?  It's still missing commas.  Also, what expected output list are you expecting for this input?  I would assume that you would expect 2D output corresponding to the 2D input so now I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your prior data was inconsistent with the length of your classes, but I see that you've edited it. So expected results would be `C, B, C, ..., C, C, C`?

Comment: @Alexander, Yes.

Comment: Note that in order to do something like `classes[X]` where `X` is an array, classes needs to be a numpy array rather than a nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over your data unless repeatedly cut and paste `result.append(classes[np.argmax(my_data[n])])` for each `n in 0:len(my_data)` which is just manually typing out the loop.

```
import numpy as np
classes = ['A', 'B', 'C']
my_data = [[2, 1, 3],
     [1, 1, 2],
     [3, 3, 3],
     [3, 1, 3],
     [3, 1, 3],
     [3, 3, 2]]

classifiedData = [classes[np.argmax(row)] for row in my_data]
print(classifiedData) # ['C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Comment: This does not match the expected output `'C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'`

Answer (score 1):

Your indexing of the data is one-based whereas python is zero-based, so just subtract one so that they are equivalent.

```
>>> [classes[max(row) - 1] for row in my_data]
['C', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
print(np.array(classes)[np.max(my_data,axis=1)-1])
```

The result:

```
['C' 'B' 'C' 'C' 'C' 'C']
```